# Using while loop for wait instead of Selenium webdriver waits

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am automating a scenario where redirection happen and result in change of page (means user will get navigated from one page to other) , although redirection is happening in the same screen, no additional window will open. I want to perform some action, once user will redirect to next screen. Without wait it would not be possible to work on this scenario. There are two approaches :

1. I was trying to use selenium wait until the URL changes to second screen .Although getting error as not able to find it in the given time.
2. I have tried using java while loop and making it wait till the URL changes using

   while(getDriver().getCurrentUrl().contains("Fraction of URL")) {
   }

This one is working for me.

I just wanted to know whether #2 will be consider a right approach or shall I dig more and go with #1 approach

***Our Application is using AJAX and our framework is based on BDD+Selenium***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the URL for the next page is, or some of it which will be different to the first page, your best bet would be to use FluentWait rather than a loop. example:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("Fraction of new URL"));
```

or if you the new URL is completely random you could use:

```
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("Fragment of URL")));
```

However this would be less reliable as it might validate it at some intermediate point, and doesn't actually validate that you have arrived at the correct page, just that you have left the last one.

What This will do is create a wait which has a maximum duration of 60 seconds, but it checks for the condition every 2 seconds. You can adjust the max time to whatever you need for your response times, but the polling ensures it only takes as long as it needs while also ensuring it has a path to fail if there is a genuine error, as opposed to the while loop which will run indefinitely if the new page doesn't load

Answer (score 1):

What if you wait until some element from redirected page is clickable or present or whatever?

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500));
```

and where you need to wait:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(WebElement));
```

There are lot of different waits: `.toBeClickabe(WebElement), .visibilityOfAllElements(List<WebElement>), .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Xpath("xpath selector"))` 
and so on..